# Merge into Java code

Tags: java

Using a sample from xSocket which will run `xSocketHandler` as a new process, I want to customize and moving all of these code into other java file, can I copy `public class xSocketDataHandler implements IDataHandler` and paste into different filename say main.java?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.BufferUnderflowException;
import java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException;
import org.xsocket.*;
import org.xsocket.connection.*;

public class xSocketDataHandler implements IDataHandler
{

    public boolean onData(INonBlockingConnection nbc) throws IOException, BufferUnderflowException, ClosedChannelException, MaxReadSizeExceededException
    {
        try
        {
            String data = nbc.readStringByDelimiter("\0");
            //nbc.write("Reply" + data + "\0");
            nbc.write("+A4\0");

            if(data.equalsIgnoreCase("SHUTDOWN"))
                xSocketServer.shutdownServer();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code wouldn't compile as is because its missing `xSocketServer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that without reducing the visibility of xSocketDataHandler to default. If you don't want to do that, your file name should be **xSocketDataHandler.java**

You must be having class xSocketDataHandler in a file of the same name already since it is public. You could move other non public classes in this file to **Main.java** instead.

Comment: I mean the main.java is an audio player and wanted to execute nbc.write("+A4\0"); to the xsocket web server

Comment: I don't think i understood you completely..but as long as you can import your INonBlockingConnection and catch of hold of its instance (nbc)...you should be able to do that.

Comment: You mean when the server started (webserver.java) and run. In main.java, I can use import org.xsocket.*; including copy and paste: public boolean onData(INonBlockingConnection nbc)...? I'm also confusing as well. If there a code for me to see. Sorry, I came from Actionscript, bad in Java.

Comment: Yes..if it works for you. But I suggest you get some basics on Java and do it when you understand completely what you are doing..unless you are experimenting/learning..I don't want to you to mess up with the code. Sorry, I could not help you much.

Answer (score 0):

A public class will need to be in a file named according to the class, so in this case it would be `xSocketDataHandler.java`.

Convention is also to name java classes starting with an upper-case letter, so it would be `public class XSocketDataHandler` and file `XSocketDataHandler.java`.  This isn't required, though.